# Function for returning year end date

Tags: vba, date

I have many financial reports, not always ending on Dec 31.

The function I'm working on should take the year-end date and return the number of days between the present date and the next year-end date, divided by 365. (Forward-looking, so if the year-end date was yesterday then the function should return 364 days, rather than 1.)

The attempt below returns 1. I believe it has to do with DateDiff.

```vb
Function dateCalc(ye As Date)
    Dim today As Date
    Dim x As Integer
    
    today = Date
    
    If ye < today Then
        x = (365 - DateDiff("d", ye, today)) / 365

    ElseIf ye > today Then
        x = DateDiff("d", ye, today) / 365

    Else
        x = 0
    
    End If
    
    dateCalc = x
End Function
```

Comment: dont work with integer (DI x As Integer), as you will need the numbers behind the comma. I would suggest double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the below derivative of your code,

```vb
Function dateCalc(ByVal YE As Date) As Double
  If YE < Today Then
    dateCalc = (365 - DateDiff("d", YE, Date)) / 365
  ElseIf YE > Today Then
    dateCalc = DateDiff("d", YE, Date) / 365
  Else
    dateCalc = 0
  End If
End Function
```

On the date 6/14/2022, we see the following:

- `?dateCalc(#6/15/2022#)` produces `-0.00273972602739726`
- `?dateCalc(#6/13/2022#)` produces `0.997260273972603`

Note that in the `YE > Today` case, the DateDiff is -1.  If you wanted a positive, negate it.  It wasn't clear from the question if this was the desired output, but the primary problem appears to be the use of `Integer` as opposed to `Double`.